# How to run a java project from command line which has got packages?

Tags: java

Am trying to run a java project which has got many jar files and packages.
I have added all the required jars in command line but am not sure how to add all the .class files which are in different packages.

This is what I have tried till now.

java -cp  /abc/hello.jar:/def/second.jar:lib/*:. com.project.HelloWorld

I want to add all the class files in the above command.

Any help would be appreciated.. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: No need to add (you already added with `.`) in case they are in the proper subfolders within this (`.`) folder.

Comment: Did you try adding the base of the class with package to classpath and run the class with full qualified name?

Comment: Have you considered creating a jar file containing the classes that you have compiled and then just include that jar on the classpath with the all your jar dependencies? Eventually this option may be more convenient, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To include the .class files you need to specify the root of the directory tree with -cp option. So if you have `package.Main` in `target/classes/package/Main.class`, then you need target/classes/ added to `-cp`:

```
java -cp lib/*.jar:target/classes/ package.Main
```

If you compile into the current directory (which is not a good thing to do, you should always use an output directory), then `.` or `./` is fine. It would search `package.Main` in the direct child directories named `./package/Main.class` then. (This also means stay away from specifying full file names for source files).

Comment: Thanks @eckes.... I tried by giving        "java -cp /abc/one.jar:lib/*:/root/workspace/prjct1/bin com.project.HelloWorld"... no luck

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, `you should always use an output directory`, why?

Comment: Because you can better clean and package the classes if they are under a common directory which does not contain anything else. Also your classpath does not contain files you don't want in it (if you use `-cp classes/` instead of `-cp .`).